# Impact of not handling the return code CURLM_CALL_MULTI_PERFORM of curl_multi_perform()

Tags: c, libcurl

I am currently studying libcurl multi API.

I am curious about what will happen if I skip checking CURLM_CALL_MULTI_PERFORM return code from curl_multi_perform().

According to https://linux.die.net/man/3/curl_multi_perform

> If you receive CURLM_CALL_MULTI_PERFORM, this basically means that you should call curl_multi_perform again, before you select() on more actions. You don't have to do it immediately, but the return code means that libcurl may have more data available to return or that there may be more data to send off before it is "satisfied". Do note that curl_multi_perform(3) will return CURLM_CALL_MULTI_PERFORM only when it wants to be called again immediately. When things are fine and there is nothing immediate it wants done, it'll return CURLM_OK and you need to wait for "action" and then call this function again.

Does anyone have any idea? I am using libcurl version 7.65.3 and my driver code is in C language. Thanks!

Comment: Sounds pretty bad if you don't! Why are you trying to avoid it?!

Comment: @ikegami its because the other documentation from https://curl.se/libcurl/c/curl_multi_perform.html does not even mention about it both description and sample code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`CURLM_CALL_MULTI_PERFORM` is deprecated since curl 7.20 and will never be returned, as documented 10 years ago.

The reason of the deprecation was rare proper use of that feature, there were numerous mistakes and misunderstandings. So since 7.20.0 CURLM_CALL_MULTI_PERFORM is no more existing.

I recommend that you consult the official manual [curl_multi_perform](https://curl.se/libcurl/c/curl_multi_perform.html) instead of 3rd party man pages.

Comment: Thank you. That explains why multi_runsingle() inside curl_multi_perform() looks like its handling CURLM_CALL_MULTI_PERFORM internally. I understand that I will consult the official manual. Again, Thanks!

Comment: After you get the basic API knowledge, I think you have got it already if you look at multi, take a look at the great [examples](https://curl.se/libcurl/c/example.html), they will help you to discover libcurl power even better.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the interesting part of `curl_multi_perform()`:

```
  data = multi->easyp;
  while(data) {
    CURLMcode result;
    SIGPIPE_VARIABLE(pipe_st);

    sigpipe_ignore(data, &pipe_st);
    result = multi_runsingle(multi, &now, data);
    sigpipe_restore(&pipe_st);

    if(result)
      returncode = result;

    data = data->next; /* operate on next handle */
  }
```

As it says there is data which will not be processed (via `multi_runsingle()`) and what that is depends on what you have in flight.

Comment: Thank you for your input. I checked multi_runsingle() internal function of multi.c. It seems that the return code for CURLM_CALL_MULTI_PERFORM is handled internally. Could you confirm it? Its quite a super function but loop condition says to redo if rc == CULRM_CALL_MULTI_PERFORM.